# I tried to call JSP through Ajax to overwrite div tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

On click to load `jsp` file in div tab without reloading page. By Ajax with jQuery.
I get URL in `urltarget`. but its not working on Ajax.

```
$("#call_emp").click(function(){
var tabs = $("#tabscontainer");
var tabid=tabs.find('ul > li[aria-selected="true"]').attr('aria-controls');
alert(tabid);
var urltarget = $("#call_emp").attr("href");
alert(urltarget);

$.ajax({
    url: urltarget,
    type: 'GET',
    data: html,
    success: function(data){$('#'+tabid).html(data);}
});

});
```

Comment: just try opening the url in new browser window and see if you get anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prenvet the default action.
Instead of data you have to write dataType:'html'

```
$("#call_emp").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   //rest of the code
   var tabs = $("#tabscontainer");
   var tabid=tabs.find('ul > li[aria-selected="true"]').attr('aria-controls');
    alert(tabid);
    var urltarget = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(urltarget);

    $.ajax({
      url: urltarget,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data){$('#'+tabid).html(data);}
   });

});
```

Comment: thanx buddy.. i wasted for 4hour tis simple error OMG!!

Answer (score 0):

`html` should be enclosed in quotes and it should be `dataType` not `data`

```
$("#call_emp").click(function(){
var tabs = $("#tabscontainer");
var tabid=tabs.find('ul > li[aria-selected="true"]').attr('aria-controls');
alert(tabid);
var urltarget = $("#call_emp").attr("href");
alert(urltarget);

$.ajax({
    url: urltarget,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    //        ^    ^ Here quotes is missing
    success: function(data){$('#'+tabid).html(data);}
});

});
```